# Confusion matrix for consonant clusters in English?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, perception, consonant-clusters

I was wondering if anybody knew of a confusion matrix for consonant clusters in the English language.  I've seen CV, VC, and CVC phoneme/syllable confusion matrices, but never any with any sort of consonant cluster.

For the research I'm doing,  it would be really, really helpful to have something like that--does anyone know of such a resource?

Thanks!

Comment: Confusion in vocal production or aural perception?

Comment: Aural perception!  How often, given a normal production of, say, a syllable with that cluster, people mistake the cluster for something else.

Comment: Has anyone axed that question before?!

Comment: Here is a link to a MA thesis with some of what you are looking for. http://circle.ubc.ca/bitstream/handle/2429/33609/UBC_1972_A6_7%20N49.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: @EdAuer Perfect! That's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks a lot!